# Frontier-pushing

Tags: grammar

Does "frontier-pushing" mean "frontier-advancing"? It seems to mean more than that, because a frontier is not only advancing himself (or pushing himself ahead), but also pushing or leading others forward to "victory" (or a better place). I am not sure.

**Frontier-pushing medical theory** and practice

Expanding the limits of health care around the world with groundbreaking research and clinical insights, to set benchmarks for progress in treatment and patient care.

Source:  New England Journal of Medicine
https://www.nejmgroup.org/learn-nejm-group/

Comment: You seem to be under the impression that a frontier is a person. Please check what the word means in a good dictionary, like this one:https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/frontier

Comment: OK. Now I guess "frontier-pushing" means "border-expanding". But the original still appears to mean more. I am not sure.

Comment: Your suggestion of border expanding seems fine to me. We also say pushing the boundaries with similar meaning.

Comment: Thank you.    Would "moving beyond borders" work there? But searching online points to the specific use of "moving beyond borders":     (quotation: Moving Beyond Borders is a long-term multifaceted initiative to create awareness our marginalized society and develop economic empowerment through community cohesion.)

Comment: "Frontier-pushing" and "expanding the limits" (also in your quote) mean basically the same thing.  It's not "moving beyond borders", it's pushing out the borders so that they include more than they did before.

Comment: Thanks..  So it sounds more forcibly or energetically?

Comment: It doesn't necessarily mean forcibly or energetically (it could be through diligent and careful research, for example).  Using "frontier" emphasizes novelty and the exploration of areas of knowledge where no one else has gone before.